# VueJS . Al redireccionar una ruta no hace la carga http desde cero, si no que coge de 'cache' (creo)

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

tengo un problema con las rutas, os comento mi problema brevemente, tengo un **vuex** con un **modulo: `user.js`**

Este `vuex - user` tiene un **action** que es :

```
getUserBySlug({commit,getters},slug){
        console.log('getUserBySlug');
        console.log('slug => '+slug);
        console.log('url get user by slug  => '+getters.getHost+'user/'+slug    );
        axios.get(getters.getHost+'user/'+slug)
            .then(
                (response)=>{
                    console.log('response')
                    console.log(response)
                    commit('setUsers',response.data);
                    commit('setStatus',response.status);
                }
            )
            .catch(
                (error)=>{
                    console.log('error')
                    console.log(error)
                    // commit('setStatus',error.response.status);
                }
            )
    }
```

Lo uso para que, en mi componente, **UserList.vue** cargue todos los usuarios:

```
<template>
 <div>
   <b-list-group>
     <b-list-group-item v-for="(user,index) in getUsers" :key="user+index" :href="'/user/show/'+user.slug">{{user.name}}</b-list-group-item>
   </b-list-group>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'UserList',
  methods:{
    loadUsers(){
      console.log('Load Users !');
      this.$store.dispatch('user/getAllUsers')
    }
  },
  computed:{
    ...mapGetters('user',{
        getUsers: 'getUsers',
        getStatus: 'getStatus'
    })
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.loadUsers();
  }

}
</script>
```

Entonces antes de que se monte el componente (`beforeMount`) carga la lista de usuarios desde el `$store`.

Hasta aqui bien, pero si os fijais, esta lista tiene unos `:href=""` para pinchar en ellos e irte a una **show de usuario**.
Esta vista de `UserShow.vue` es la siguiente:

```
<template>
 <div>
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12">
         <h1>User Show</h1>
         <div v-if="user!=null">
           <div class="row d-flex justify-content-start">
             <div class="col-5 w-100">
               <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info" :href="'/user/create/'+user.slug">Editar</a>
               <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger" href="#"  @click="deleteUser">Elimiar</a>
             </div>
           </div>
           <hr>
           <h4>{{user.name}}</h4>
           <h4>{{user.email}}</h4>
           <h4>{{user.created_at}}</h4>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .disabled_link{
    color: currentColor;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
</style>
<script>
import axios from "axios";
import {mapGetters, mapState} from "vuex";
import user from "@/store/modules/user";

export default {
  name: 'UserCreate',
  methods:{
    loadUser(){
      this.$store.dispatch('user/getUserBySlug',this.$route.params.slug);
    },
    deleteUser(){
      console.log('delete user')
      this.$store.dispatch('user/deleteUser',this.$route.params.slug);
      if (this.getStatus === 200){
        this.$router.push('/user/list');
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState('user',{
      user : state => state.users
    }),
    ...mapGetters('user',{
      getStatus:'getStatus'
    })
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadUser();
  }
}
</script>
```

Esa vista tiene un boton para borrar el usuario que tienes, cuando se le da llama a :
`this.$store.dispatch('user/deleteUser',this.$route.params.slug);` , es muy simple, borra el usuario mediante su slug (*funciona perfectamente*).

**Una vez borrado quiero q vuelva a ir a la vista de `UserList.vue`** para que el usuario siga haciendo lo que quiere. **Aqui empieza el problema**, yo hago el redirect con : `this.$router.push('/user/list');` y me carga la lista de usuarios, **pero sigue estando el usuario que he borrado**, entonces si actualizo la pagina (`F5`) carga otra vez la lista pero esta vez bien, sin el usuario que he borrado.

No se si el `$route` trabaja con la cache y por eso me esta fastidiando. No se la verdad. ¿Como podria hacer que no tirara de cahce o forzarle a que haga la carga de usuarios siempre que entre en ese componente?

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una manera para que recarge la pagina, no se si es la mejor, pero es la que he contrado y la que me voy a quedar por ahora, insisto, si alguien tiene alguna otra forma de recargar los datos tras un `$router.push()` que lo deje aqui. Gracias.

---

Con el **hook** `beforeUpdate` he conseguido recargar la pagina cuando accedo a esta desde otra, aqui un ejemplo de lo que he hecho:

```
  beforeUpdate() {
    this.loadUsers(); // this.$store.dispatch('user/getAllUsers')
  }
```